# MATLAB - save command window contents (but process already running)?

Tags: matlab

I have this optimization problem that runs for hours. I was hoping it would be over but it's not. I'm at a lab pc and I wdon't want someone to switch off the simulation when I leave. Of course I could write a sign board. Wondering if there is any other way to tell matlab to save the output of the current running command to a file or switch diary on while another process is running?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: windows xp. Is there a way?